# WCF Service Design example

Tags: wcf, msmq

I have to create a WCF service that will accept thousands of requests every 5 minutes, which each request passing a small (1-5KB) text file.

The service will pass the file contents to another assembly, which will process the lines and insert some records into the database. Nothing too heavy on this side.

I need help on the following aspects:

- Which WCF configuration should I use that will give me the best performance? The calls to the service will come from the internet not an internal LAN.
- The service will accept requests every 5 minutes, which means I have only 5 minutes to process all the requests before the next cycle. Is MSMQ the best solution here?

Any examples online I can read?

Comment: Do you mean that your service accepts calls for one minute, every five minutes?

Comment: I read it to mean that there are thousands of clients, who try to hit hte service every five minutes, but since there are so many, it'll end up being thousands per minute?

Comment: Nate is right

The service will be called every 5 minutes by thousands of clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For best performance, I'll assume you're talking about less latency. You should pick a TCP transport, like `net.tcp`. This document can help you to decide [Choosing a Transport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx)

About that MSMQ part: you'll receive a lot request and just start processing them after 5 minutes? If yes, your choice is correct: MSMQ will keep that request queue and you can work on them asynchronously.

Comment: Rubens,

Processing time will be probably more than 5 minutes so queuing I think is the only solution here.. My question is if MSMQ is the best option.

Comment: If you already have MSMQ working, yes, it's a good choice. But you can also to build your queue mechanism, by storing pending items on a database.

Comment: I don't have MSMQ in place and this is my main concern, starting one.
Storing items in database is my favorite option, since is clean, easy to implement and is something I've done before.. 8-)

Comment: If you have time, I would to suggest to learn MSMQ; if not, take that known road

Answer (score 0):

Use NetTCPbinding

[Optimizing WCF Web Service Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377061(BTS.10).aspx)

[Creating high performance WCF services](http://weblogs.asp.net/sweinstein/archive/2009/01/03/creating-high-performance-wcf-services.aspx)